# I want to pull distinct values for 2 columns in the same table and associated unique value columns for these unique values in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

The table is something like:

```
User_id      Bidid        timestamp ... (about 25-30 more columns)
```

How do I pull all the distinct user ids with all the distinct `Bidid`'s associated with them and also the timestamp which is unique to each `Bidid`?

Comment: First read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, then edit your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`select distinct` comes to mind:

```
select distinct User_id, Bidid, timestamp 
from t;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this could be idea  you are looking for, it depends of the version SQL/environment/etc:

```
 SELECT USER_ID, BIDID, TIMESTAMP, ...
 FROM THE_TABLE
 WHERE BIDID=(SELECT DISTINCT BIDIT FROM THE_TABLE)
```

or

```
 SELECT USER_ID, BIDID, TIMESTAMP,..
 FROM THE_TABLE
 WHERE BIDID IN (SELECT DISTINCT BIDIT FROM THE_TABLE)
```